# A-frame.js version 0.8 can not render 360 image

Tags: aframe, webvr

We are working on a basic template of rendering a 360 image on webpage.
Recently we upgraded A-frame.js version from 0.7 to 0.8. The image rendering stopped when we upgraded to v0.8, 
Inspecting in Console we noticed that there was a warning

> "[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-00000000068E6AA0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering."

We are using the 360 image of dimension **4096*2048** bound to `<a-sky>` element.
We also tried A-frame demo from the a-frame site with pointing it to the master branch. It seems to fail as well.
Here is the [demo glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/horse-stretch).

We also found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928118/aframe-v-0-8-0-renders-a-blank-page-with-no-error-in-console).
What are we missing?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the asset url, glitch won't see the image by name.

Instead of `src: file.jpg` you need go to the assets tab, click the image, and get its URL.

Remixed glitch [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/sour-ocean?path=index.html:8:74).

Comment: Thank you for answering. I was not able to get this demo work locally, had to up shift the version of A-frame to 0.8.2 to get it work. (in case if anyone faces same issue.)